# I need software that selects a random item from a list, to help with indecisiveness

Tags: windows, offline

A web-based example of what I'm looking for is [Easy Decision Maker](http://easydecisionmaker.com).

As per the example, the question and options will always be the same. I will need to input several options (10+), save them so that I don't have to input them repeatedly, and have the tool accessible from my desktop while I am offline.

Comment: What you need is a Jump To Conclusions mat.

Answer (score 4):

An easy and versatile method would be to use a spreadsheet. [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/download) is free. Write your list, one entry per cell, and in another cell you can enter:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(1,10)
```

Where 1 is the line your list starts at, and 10 is the line it ends at. If you want it to display the randomly selected option in a cell instead of a number, change it to:

```
=INDIRECT("A"&RANDBETWEEN(1,10))
```

Where "A" is the column containing the list. You can use <kbd>F9</kbd> to recalculate and get a new selection.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would do it in PHP from a similar site : https://gooddecisionmaker.com

You could run this in WAMP, so on a local server environment.

```
$result = rand (1,10);
```

For the maximum and a minimum, you could do something like this:

```
if (empty($_POST['question'])) {
$problem = "1";
goto ask;
}
if (empty($_POST['answer1'])) {
$problem = "2";
$question = $_POST['question'];
goto ask;
}

$highest = "2";

if (!empty($_POST['answer3'])) { $highest = "3"; }
if (!empty($_POST['answer4'])) { $highest = "4"; }
if (!empty($_POST['answer5'])) { $highest = "5"; }
if (!empty($_POST['answer6'])) { $highest = "6"; }
if (!empty($_POST['answer7'])) { $highest = "7"; }
if (!empty($_POST['answer8'])) { $highest = "8"; }
if (!empty($_POST['answer9'])) { $highest = "9"; }
if (!empty($_POST['answer10'])) { $highest = "10"; }

$result = rand (1,$highest);
```